# Convert bytes -> string -> back to bytes, and get original value

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I checked all Stackoverflow questions on this matter and none can answer my problem.I need to convert `\\` to `\`.
**Edited:**
This is what I am trying:

```
>>> a = b'\xe5jb\x8c?Q$\xf3\x1d\x97^\xfa3O\xa6U.txt'
>>> b = str(a)
>>> b
"b'\\xe5jb\\x8c?Q$\\xf3\\x1d\\x97^\\xfa3O\\xa6U.txt'"
>>> b = b.replace('b\'','')
>>> b = b[:len(b)-1]
>>> b
'\\xe5jb\\x8c?Q$\\xf3\\x1d\\x97^\\xfa3O\\xa6U.txt'
>>> c = bytes(b,'utf8')
>>> c
b'\\xe5jb\\x8c?Q$\\xf3\\x1d\\x97^\\xfa3O\\xa6U.txt'
>>> a == c
False
```

How do I make `a==c` True? I tried

```
 .replace("\\\\","\\")
```

but this doesn't help. The string remains the same. I need to store the byte in variable 'a' to a file as a text and call it back. Python-3.8, Windows=10

Comment: what is this `d` in `b=b[:len(d)-1]`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The `b'abc'` is for bytes. In string `\` is used as escape character. So `\\` means keep ignore `\`

Comment: Please state the question in words, so it isn't completely dependent on code and can't be found by keyword search. You're trying to convert a bytes object `a` into the equivalent string `b` then back into bytes `c`, and get the original bytes. The escaping of `\` is just a symptom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `c` to a string with the `decode` method, and then use `ast.literal_eval` to evaluate it as a bytes literal after wrapping it with `b'...'`:

```
from ast import literal_eval
a = b'\xe5jb\x8c?Q$\xf3\x1d\x97^\xfa3O\xa6U.txt'
c = b'\\xe5jb\\x8c?Q$\\xf3\\x1d\\x97^\\xfa3O\\xa6U.txt'
c = literal_eval("b'%s'" % c.decode())
print(a == c)
```

This outputs: `True`

Comment: this answer is Perfect! i need to give `c=literal_eval("b'%s'" % c.decode())`

Comment: is there anyway to stop bytes() from returning the output?

Answer (score 0):

Use .replace() function for string